# rake aborted while using gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi am having this in my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

and in my database.yml I have written this code

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: railsquiz
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  password: test
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now I had run bundle install and got this version of mysql2-0.2.24. 
When am doing

`rake db:create`

its giving me error

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `require'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize_tasks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/Desktop/clones/railsquiz/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails-quiz/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now please guide how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: gem 'rake', '10.1.0' add this to your gem file and then bundle install

Comment: still its giving error

Comment: how many rake versions are installed? by using ` gem list rake`

Comment: only one rake-10.1.0

Comment: have you run that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

in your Gemfile and then running rake as

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: go to your Rakefile and on line 7 set rdoc/task  instead of  rake/rdoctask , or delete line completely.